# Template appearance from the bottom-Twitter bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I open Template it appears from the bottom and Scroll bar of site appears at the bottom of the site instead of appearing at the beginning of the site..

I use the version of the bootstrap 3 and supportive of the Arabic language..

any help?

Thank you very much ..

Comment: Could you show us an example?

Comment: Note the picture, and noted Scroll Bar: 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99822344/prob.png

When I open the site appears from the bottom instead of the top of appearing ..

Comment: Do you have any anchor tags applied to your URL (`http://example.com/#anchor`)?

Comment: I did not raise the site after, I send you the Index?

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue on JSFiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I apologize for the delay to respond, but the power went out, 

regarding the problem has been successfully solved the problem, I put the input in the form  autofocus = ""  This is the site appears from the bottom..
thanks you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove

> outfocuse=""

from any tag at the bottom of the page